# Automatically send out will and video at death

Tags: web-apps, email

Is there a web application paid or not paid that will email automatically send out my will and video at my death?

Maybe the app periodically checks my gmail logins to determine if I am still an active person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking about is not a new concept at all. It's called a [dead man's trigger, or a dead man's switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man%27s_switch). I was thinking of several ways to do this when I `Googled` the term. Then, in the Google results, there is someone [offering this service](https://www.deadmansswitch.net/). So - easy, and cost $20 for your lifetime.

If you're more of a "DIY" person, you could create something very similar [using `cron`, and a small app to send yourself an email](https://github.com/seamusdemora/PiPyMailer) reminder. The code at the end of that link will get you started, but you'll still have some work to do adapting it to your demise rather than `@reboot`  :)

Comment: DIY a dead man switch seems like a bad iedea

Comment: @William: I don't know why you'd say that. BTW, you seem to have mis-spelled a word in your comment.

Comment: @William: Hello - I died last year, and this comment is coming to you posthumously from my dead-man's trigger. So - yeah - proof that my answer was correct. LOL